# How do you deploy Mojolicious applications onto production servers?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I've been developing my first Mojolicious application.  Til now I've been running it from the development directory, but now I want to install on the production servers.  `mojo generate app` produced the directories templates/ and public/ which I have been using to store templates and static files.  I created a simple distribution with Dist::Zilla, but I couldn't get at templates/ and public/ during runtime.

The solution I've come with is to move templates/ and public/ into a new directory share/, and let File::ShareDir (or Dist::Zilla's ShareDir plugin) pick it up so that I can configure the appropriate paths in my *_mode methods:

```
sub development_mode{
    my $app = shift;
    push @{$app->static->paths}, rel2abs(catdir('share', 'public') );
    push @{$app->renderer->paths}, rel2abs(catdir('share', 'templates') );
}

sub production_mode{
    my $app = shift;
    push @{$app->static->paths}, catdir(dist_dir('FooBar'), 'public') ;
    push @{$app->renderer->paths}, catdir(dist_dir('FooBar'), 'templates') ;
}
```

Is there a more official way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that's how I do it, both for [Galileo](http://metacpan.org/module/Galileo) and my more generic plugin which does this for you: [Mojolicious::Plugin::InstallablePaths](https://metacpan.org/source/JBERGER/Mojolicious-Plugin-InstallablePaths-0.03/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/InstallablePaths.pm).